# powermock inorder

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I use PowerMock to mock static methods. I need to verify order of static and non static method calls. Is it possible to do using PowerMock?

**UPD**

I use powermockito extension to mock static methods, so solution with powermockito extension is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not to be implemented http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=279&q=inorder